# Save input values in reactive variables (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using reactive vars to manage visibility of my `input` fields depenging on user's choice `select`. But when I choose one `option`, write anything in shown input, then go to the second option, and finally when I come back to the firs one, the input `value` disappears. Is there any way to keep that data untill `confirm` button pressing to confirm once all the fields values under all the options?

Here are two input groups that are displayed, when option is set:

```
   <template name="addTour">
   <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="tour-dropdown">Программа</label>
<div class="dropdown col-xs-8 form-group form-horisontal">
    <select class="form-control" id="tour-dropdown">
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
</div>
{{#if a}}
<div class="container-fluid">
{{> textfield label='a option' id='transfer-city-from'}}
{{> confirm add='a option'}}
</div>
{{/if}}
{{#if b}}
<div class="container-fluid">
{{> textfield label='b option' id='transfer-city-from'}}
{{> confirm add='b option'}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

And some JS here that manages `reactive variables` to do all that job:

```
Template.addTour.onCreated( function () {
this.a = new ReactiveVar( false );
this.b = new ReactiveVar( false );


Template.addTour.helpers( {
a: function () {
    return Template.instance().a.get();
},
b: function () {
    return Template.instance().b.get();
}
}
});

Template.addTour.events( {
'change select': function ( event, template ) {
    if ( $( event.target ).val() === "a" ) {
        template.a.set( true );
    } else {
        template.a.set( false );
    };
    if ( $( event.target ).val() === "b" ) {
        template.b.set( true );
    } else {
        template.b.set( false );
    };
}
});
```

Or I shoud better use `display:block` and `display:none` ?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning! You can [edit] your question to include the needed informations. Note that in your link, the example would not be minimal. Please include the smallest possible amount of code needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I looked at your gist - my initial sense is that you could make this much much simpler. DRY! Firstly since your select is single-select you only need one reactive variable to hold the select state, not 8 of them. To your question itself - if you show/hide html using `{{#if }}` in spacebars then those elements are actually added or removed from the DOM along with any data in their `<input>` elements. You're right that you'd be better off using `display:none` to control visibility. You might want to even reconsider if you need 8 variations of the form or if you can abstract some of it into data.

Comment: I should spend more time in learning. Thank you, Michel. Now I have more understanding about how spacebars work.. As I understood, I'd better use `display:none` and **jQuery** to do that job, right? Or I can still use `reactive vars` on some way? Sorry, I didn't get the suggestion about `abstract` and `data`, I am still amateur in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to resolve my problem with `jQuery` and it's `hide()` / `show()` options.

Here is the code:

```
<template name="addTour">
<label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="tour-dropdown">Программа</label>
<div class="dropdown col-xs-8 form-group form-horisontal">
    <select class="form-control" id="tour-dropdown" >
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
</div>


    <div class="container-fluid" id="a">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form class='form-horizontal'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h1>A option</h1>
                    {{> timepicker label='время прибытия' id='transfer-time-a'}}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <div class="container-fluid" id="b">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form class='form-horizontal'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h1>B option</h1>
                    {{> timepicker label='время прибытия' id='transfer-time-b'}}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jQuery works for me in this view:

```
Dropdown = $('#tour-dropdown');
$('#a').hide();
$('#b').hide();
select = this.value;
Dropdown.change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'a') {
        $('#a').show();
        console.log('A option');
    } else $('#a').hide();
    if ($(this).val() === 'b') {
        $('#b').show();
        console.log('B option');
    } else $('#b').hide();// hide div if value is not "custom"
});
```

It works fine and keep values inside all the hidden inputs, so I can submit all of them once.